# Cookies in $http request

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cookies

When doing a request using $http from a page (like /foo.html) to the same origin (like /api/v1/foo) all cookies set for this origin will be attached to the request.

Is possible to modify this behaviour and remove the cookies because they are there for non-AngularJS purpose and they increase the size of each AJAX request?

Comment: not really. ajax requests are just http requests. there's really no practical/operational difference between "send form fields via ajax" and "send form fields by clicking submit button", except ajax requests tend to have an extra header saying it was done via ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know exactly which cookies you want to remove, and most importantly, which **cookies are safe to remove to preserve the correct behavior**, you can use [`$cookieStore` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore), e.g. `$cookieStore.remove("someKey")`. Since AngularJS 1.4 `$cookieStore` is deprecated, so [`$cookies` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) should be used instead, e.g. `$cookies.remove("someKey")`. Please note that both of them require the [`ngCookies`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) module to be installed.

Comment: That would works very well as I know the cookies in target.